# Dividing a array to into k parts using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am thinking about how to break an array into k parts using DP with the following requirement.

> Array A of size n divided into k parts
>
> - All elements are positive integers and order is fixed.
> - The maximum difference between the sum of elements in 2 groups is minimized.

You may think of a scenario: there is a book with many chapters and I want to put different characters in different volumes as even as possible.

It is hard to think how to do that because if I use DP and add one $a_i$ at a time, the algorithm will always put the newly added $a_i$ to a new group until all group is filled.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify "The maximum difference between the max and min sum of elements of 2 groups is minimized"? I see at least 2 ways to interpret this. One is: For a partition $P$ of $A$ into $G_1, \dots, G_k$, let $a(P)$ be the maximum, across all distinct pairs of sets $G_i, G_j$, of $\sum_{x\in G_i}x + \sum_{y\in G_j}y$, and let $b(P)$ be the similarly-defined minimum; find a partition $P$ minimising $a(P)-b(P)$.

Comment: Is it better? Basically, what I meant is summing all elements in a group and the maximum difference between the two groups.

Comment: So it has to be the group that has the largest and smallest sum of elements respectively. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You could define $f(m, i, j)$ as the maximum, over all ways of partitioning the first $i$ numbers into $j$ blocks each having sum $\le m$, of the minimum block sum (or -1 if no such partition is possible). This leads to an $O(tkn^2)$-time solution, where $t$ is the sum of all input numbers. There are several opportunities for optimisation, e.g., no need to try $m < \lceil t/k \rceil$.

Comment: With $k = 2$, this is the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) and it is NP-complete (or I didn't understand the problem).

Comment: @Nathaniel: I interpreted "part" to mean "contiguous block", but if a single part can be split across multiple contiguous blocks then you're right. OP please clarify either way.

Comment: Yes, coz the order is fixed.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. You may think of a scenario: there is a book with many chapters and I want to put different characters in different volumes as even as possible.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify. Don't leave clarifications in the comments - [edit] the question, then flag comments that are no longer needed once the feedback has been addressed.